# Select DISTINCT column in a DISTINCT condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select distinct values from 'num' when it's status is 'YES' only, not including 'NO' at once?

Table:

```
+--------+-----+--------+
| id     | num | status |
+--------+-----+--------+
| 364519 | AAA | YES    |
| 364522 | BBB | YES    |
| 364525 | AAA | NO     |
| 364527 | CCC | YES    |
| 364530 | DDD | YES    |
| 364532 | EEE | YES    |
| 364535 | FFF | YES    |
| 364537 | DDD | YES    |
| 364538 | DDD | NO     |
| 364539 | FFF | NO     |
+--------+-----+--------+
```

needed Result:

```
+--------+-----+--------+
| id     | num | status |
+--------+-----+--------+
| 364522 | BBB | YES    |
| 364527 | CCC | YES    |
| 364532 | EEE | YES    |
+--------+-----+--------+
```

Comment: What ID is it you are showing in your result? Say, if one num has multiple 'YES' and no 'NO', which ID would you want to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, num,'yes' AS status
FROM tab
GROUP BY num
HAVING SUM(status='NO') = 0;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=3df356239064cf887d3c1140dedf30e4)**

Comment: Not sure why, but this one makes my skin crawl

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of other approaches.  (having seems the cleanest)

Divide the data into two sets and make sure the "A" set has no data in the "B" set
First approach using a outer join  only return records in "A" set where no related num is found in "B" set.

```
SELECT Min(A.ID) as ID, A.num, A.status
FROM table A
LEFT JOIN table B
  on A.Num = B.Num
 and B.Status = 'NO'
WHERE A.Status = 'YES'
  and B.Num is null
GROUP BY A.Num, A.Status
```

Second approach using a not exists.  similar only num records in "A" set not in "B" set.

```
SELECT min(A.ID) as ID, A.Num, A.Status
FROM table A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM Table B
                  WHERE A.Num = B.Num
                    and B.Status = 'NO')
GROUP BY A.Num, A.Status
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE status='YES' AND num NOT IN (SELECT num FROM table WHERE status='NO')
```

Or this

```
SELECT * FROM table t
WHERE t.status='YES' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE status='NO' AND num=t.num)
```

Answer (score 0):

select distinct(num),id,status from table where status='YES'

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `group by` cluase :

```
select min(id) as id, num, 'YES' as status
from table t
group by num
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'YES';
```